# No Bash completion in VNC connections?

Tags: bash, vnc, auto-completion

bash completion is not working with a vnc connection. I works if I login with ssh, but not with xterm/bash in a vnc connection. I tried with different display managers and with different machines, no solution. I checked .bashrc - it is enabled. I have no idea where to look now.

Comment: What's the value of BASH_COMPLETION?  (`echo $BASH_COMPLETION` would display it.)

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyway or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reason(s) why you want it open. Regards

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue on 12.04.
I've set up a new VM with XFCE & SNC'ing into the instance [link url=http://www.abdevelopment.ca/blog/start-vnc-server-ubuntu-boot]as per guide[/link].
bash_completion works OK if I SSH in, but not in terminals in the VNC session. 
echo of $BASH_COMPLETION returns "/etc/bash_completion" in both SSH & VNC sessions